# Draw very large, detailed picture with TikZ (Error: Dimension too large)

Tags: tikz-pgf, errors, pdftex

I want to draw a very large standalone diagram with TikZ, consisting of lines, arcs, circles and text. Unfortunately, also for moderate coordinate values, I get the error "Dimension too large" when compiling with pdflatex.

I read that the usual solution is either rescaling all coordinates or using pgfplots. However, both options seem not too straightforward, as I both need a fairly reasonable resolution (at least 0.01, but coordinate values 1000+) and it is more a diagram/art than a data plot.

Here is a minimum example that produces this error. No text and arcs included yet.

```
\documentclass[crop,tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\filldraw(0, 0) circle(1 pt);
\draw (105,3) -- (0,0);
\draw (577.2,12) -- (532,9);
\draw (-504,21.02) -- (-504.2,18);
\filldraw(-442, 21) circle(1 pt);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Best would be a drop-in workaround or fix for TikZ, but if this is not possible I may also consider not using TikZ or even LaTeX at all. The tex source is generated using a python script anyways.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Are you aware, that you require that image is 11 meter wide and more 1 meter height?

Comment: If the drawing code is generated from a program and is similar to what you've posted, you may be better off generating something like svg directly.

Comment: @Zarko yes, I'm very aware of this fact; as mentioned, this is more a piece of art than a document to print. But in fact, this may be the error, as it could be larger than the PDF maximum page size.

Comment: `Per the ISO 32000 standard for PDF, the page dimension limit is 14,400 PDF units in each direction. A PDF unit is 1/72 of an inch so the limit equates to a maximum page size of 200 x 200 inches. (5080 x 5080 mm).` But of course we all have seen posters larger than 10m x 10m. Maybe you can contact your local printing shop and ask them how is that even possible. (I suspect they just scale everything down.)

Comment: Also there are things like `PyPDF` and `jsPDF`, and those languages are familiar with large numbers.

Comment: A accuracy of 0.01 over an amplitude of 1000 (10µm/1m) is not reasonable to display or print...